# Postgres.app won't start

Tags: postgres.app

I am running `Yosemite` and have had the `Postgres.app` running with no issues for months.  I started the app today and got this error

```
Could not initialize database cluster.
initdb: could not create directory "I": Permission denied
```

What could cause this to happen and what do I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This baffled me for ages too.  Turns out I had errantly typed while the preferences dialog was open which changed the data directory.  Using 'default' fixed my issue.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Looks like a bug in the app.

Comment: Hmm maybe.. but in my case it was a bug in the chair.  Although it seems odd that I also typed an 'I'... perhaps it is the result of a common but misfingered shortcut sequence

Comment: Oh yeah - I got it. If you open the preference panel and hit escape to close it (standard modal behaviour) it autosuggests 'I'

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also typed an "I" which seems suspicious, but lucygenik already explained the problem. Anyway, thanks for letting me avoid n unnecessary search for this silly issue.

Comment: @lucygenik thanks man. I seem more a bug, how come everyone typing same character?

Comment: As in my earlier comment I think it's because it's a natural reflex to hit escape to close the modal and when you do that it injects the |